# How to compile rtaudio on windows with mingw?

Tags: c++, mingw, rtaudio

I want to use rtaudio in my project. I am following instructions in install.txt which tells me to run ./configure then make.

When I run make I get bunch of warnings:

```
$ make
Making all in .
make[1]: Entering directory `/c/Users/Onur/Desktop/Development/rtaudio-4.1.2'
  CXX      RtAudio.lo
In file included from RtAudio.cpp:43:0:
RtAudio.h:585:11: error: 'uintptr_t' does not name a type
   typedef uintptr_t ThreadHandle;
           ^
In file included from RtAudio.cpp:43:0:
RtAudio.h:608:3: error: 'ThreadHandle' does not name a type
   ThreadHandle thread;
   ^
In file included from RtAudio.cpp:3682:0:
c:\mingw\include\audioclient.h:166:50: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ';' token
 DEFINE_ENUM_FLAG_OPERATORS(AUDCLNT_STREAMOPTIONS);
                                                  ^
c:\mingw\include\audioclient.h:206:13: error: '_In_' has not been declared
             _In_  AUDCLNT_SHAREMODE ShareMode,
             ^
c:\mingw\include\audioclient.h:206:37: error: expected ',' or '...' before 'ShareMode'
             _In_  AUDCLNT_SHAREMODE ShareMode,
                                     ^
```

Would be awesome if someone could guide me on this.

Comment: Looks like it refers to some non standard stuff. Are you sure you have all dependency packages installed?

Comment: I am using wasapi. What dependencies is rtaudio depended on?

Comment: I don't know in particular, but it seems that [`uintptr_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer) want's you to have either C99 or C++11.

Comment: Seems like you're right. Adding -std=c+11 fixed this problem, but it can't find audioclient.h. I guess it is wasapi related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution using cmake on windows:

1. Simply download cmake gui
2. Get the rtaudio source from github or their official webpage
3. Open RtAudio.h and include math.h
4. Generate build files with cmake gui to a seperate folder (toggle BUILD_TESTING off before configuring)
5. Navigate to build folder using a terminal. And run mingw32-make. Make sure mingw/bin is added to path so it ca find mingw32-make.
6. You should have three files: librtaudio.dll librtaudio.dll.a and
   librtaudio_static.a

This worked for me.